# BigQuery Automation using PUB/SUB trigger?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

During bigquery automation i am deploying this https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron sample code. What changes i need to make in this. And not getting what is url, description. How to set url?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. That sample code has a walkthrough that explains each step of the process. There is no mention of a URL anywhere because it deals with task scheduling.

Comment: in this github sample there is appengine inside that cron.yaml and app.yaml is there, in that url is there.

Comment: Have a general query how this function will take my saved queries from BigQuery?

Comment: Or do u have any other option to automate bigquery ?

Comment: https://shinesolutions.com/2017/11/01/scheduling-bigquery-jobs-using-google-apps-script/ may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a BigQuery Automation using http trigger, hope it could be helpful. Here is what I did:

1. Create a Cloud Function that runs BigQuery query.

   - Keep the HTTP trigger url for step2.  https://[your_project_ID].cloudfunctions.net/[your_cloud_funtion_name]
2. Create an App Engine App.

   - Since [we cannot specify a Google Cloud Endpoint in the url field of a cron job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron#calling_google_cloud_endpoints), I created a handler to send the request to HTTP trigger url
3. Create cron.yaml that calls this handler every x minutes.
4. Deploy the application to App Engine.

   ```
   $ gcloud app deploy app.yaml \cron.yaml
   ```

If you need more details, please post a comment and I will be happy to help.